# Where is Wengert List in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

TensorFlow use reverse-mode automatic differentiation(reverse mode AD), as shown in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675.

Reverse mode AD need a data structure called a Wengert List - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Reverse_accumulation.

However, searching through the TensorFlow repository with the keyword "Wengert List", I get nothing.

Do they use a different name, or do they get rid of Wengert List? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AD terminology is very old. It was invented when there was no Python and things were complicated. Nowadays you could just use a regular Python list for that purpose.

Implementation of reverse AD is in `gradients` function of `gradients_impl.py` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/37aa430d84ced579342a4044c89c236664be7f68/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L397)

The data-structure used to store the tape is initialized on [line 532](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/37aa430d84ced579342a4044c89c236664be7f68/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L532) and it's a Python Queue

```
# Initialize queue with to_ops.
queue = collections.deque()
```

Comment: Actually, machines were simpler back then but harder to use, more "austere". Now syntactic sugar is everywhere, but when it breaks .. well you create an issue.

Answer (score 5):

> However, searching through the TensorFlow repository with the keyword "Wengert List", but I get nothing.

This is because TensorFlow is not *tape based AD*, it is *graph based AD* system.

Wengert list would be the tape describing the order in which operations were originally executed.

There is also *source code transformation based AD* and a nice example of that system is [Tangent](https://github.com/google/tangent).

Nowadays almost no one uses tape (Wengert list) any more. Check for instance what [PyTorch does](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BJJsrmfCZ) (Page 2).

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 2 uses a Wengert List (a tape) as does JAX and Autograd. This is because these tools keep track of the operations on variables with some sort of `gradient_tape`.

Tensorflow 1 did not use a Wengert list to keep track of what computation was being performed, instead it used a static graph to keep track of what computation was being performed. This had certain performance benefits, but limited what TensorFlow 1 was capable of doing.